# gem install nmatrix failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I type in the command `gem install matrix`. It report an "fatal" error that the stdio.h is missing! why? and how to fix it? Thank you! The bug report below:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing nmatrix:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151212-6597-v5fw6g.rb extconf.rb

/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

checking for apparent GNU g++ binary with C++0x/C++11 support... 4.9
using C++ standard... c++11
g++ reports version... gcc
creating nmatrix_config.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling nmatrix.cpp
In file included from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:0,
                 from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from nmatrix.cpp:34:
/Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [nmatrix.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: Yap.                                                                                                                 xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates.                                                                                          I guess there maybe some incidence that make the stdio.h out of place?

Comment: I think your environment may be outdated. Try uninstalling and installing Xcode again, then as F. Fiebig said, `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

The error is similar to a bunch other questions, for them this seemed to fix it.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: By typing in this command. It shows that command line tools are already installed. I can compile other software of packages successfully and other gems that may need building Native Extension. But some gems failed, such as nmatrix and sciruby-full..Can you help me ?